# TimeZones in Google Web Toolkit (GWT), GAE & Google Cloud SQL (mySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, gwt, timezone

When I run the code below locally, the Date & Time returns as UTC correctly (on the client side). When I run a GAE server locally, and write to mySQL database residing in the Google Cloud, it stores the date as UTC properly as well.

However, when I deploy the webapp to Google App Engine (GAE), the time is being stored as UTC + 4 hours. The same mySQL server in the Google Cloud is set to the Eastern/NY timezone, which means mySQL server is compensating to (what it thinks is) UTC by adding 4 hours to my passed in UTC time.

In other words, mySQL adds 4 hours when GAE sends it the value... but does not when my local server does. So I guess the question is, why does it store properly when I run off my local GAE, but add 4 hours when ran on GAE?

The TimeZone object is from the com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone library. How can I guarantee a UTC datetime no matter where my client or server sits? My app cannot rely on any server for the time, as it will be functioning offline most of the time.

```
private static Date getNowDateTimeUTC() {
    DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String utcDateString = df.format(new Date(), TimeZone.createTimeZone(0));
    Date returnDate = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(utcDateString);
    returnDate.setTime((returnDate.getTime() / 1000) * 1000); // rid the milliseconds
    return returnDate;
}
```

Comment: Avoid using Date class, it's flawed. Java 8 has Instant class for that.

Comment: GAE still only supports Java 7 :(

Comment: I am wondering if storing the date in epoch seconds make sesnse... same storage size... and mySQL won't try to adjust the date's timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing the number of seconds since epoch instead of an actual date value. This way, mySQL doesn't try to fix the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai"));
```

Maybe you can set the time zone like this which you want. Asia/Shanghai replace your time zone！

Answer (score 0):

In my company's project we use [jsTimezoneDetect library](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) on the client side to detect timezones with JavaScript. It is easy to use library.